# CSS - Keep z-index until transition ended

Tags: html, css

I have this simple grid here:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 5px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 3fr);
        }
        .box {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 100%;
            color: #fff;
            transition: 1000ms;
        }
            .box .square {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border: 2px solid;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background: #101318;
                display: flex;
                text-align: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .box:hover {
                transform: scale(2);
                z-index: 2;
            }

        .r1 {  grid-row: 20;  }
        .r2 {  grid-row: 21;  }  
        .c1 {  grid-column: 2;  }
        .c2 {  grid-column: 3;  }           

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid">

        <div class="box r1 c1">
            <div class="square">A</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box r2 c1">
            <div class="square">B</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box r1 c2">
            <div class="square">C</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box r2 c2">
            <div class="square">D</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html
```

When I hover over a box, it gets bigger and comes into the foreground, but as soon as I leave it gets smaller, as it should, but it also goes back into the back, but I want it to stay in the foreground, until it is small again, and only be overlapped by the currently hovered box.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index: 1;` on the `.box` class to avoid it jumping into the back.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 5px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 3fr);
        }
        .box {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 100%;
            color: #fff;
            transition: 1000ms;
            z-index: 1;
        }
            .box .square {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border: 2px solid;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background: #101318;
                display: flex;
                text-align: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .box:hover {
                transform: scale(2);
                z-index: 2;
            }

        .r1 {  grid-row: 20;  }
        .r2 {  grid-row: 21;  }  
        .c1 {  grid-column: 2;  }
        .c2 {  grid-column: 3;  }           

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid">

        <div class="box r1 c1">
            <div class="square">A</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box r2 c1">
            <div class="square">B</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box r1 c2">
            <div class="square">C</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box r2 c2">
            <div class="square">D</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: Thanks!! I did z-index 0 instead of 1, and it is perfect!

Comment: @Cosemuckel Appreciate if you can upvote and mark the answer as accepted as it would help other users who are looking for similar solutions.